# Why with output redirection "Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS" is printed as a last line?

Tags: java, windows, io-redirection

Consider following class:

```
public class SleepMessages {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.err.println("Hi stderr!");
        System.out.println("Hi stdout!");
    }
}
```

I have JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS set:

```
C:\temp>echo %JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS%
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

When I call the class above directly -- I'm getting following output and line "Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS" is the first one as expected:

```
C:\temp>java -cp . SleepMessages
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Hi stderr!
Hi stdout!
```

However, if I'm calling the same class with the redirection, the line "Picked up ..." is the last one:

```
C:\temp>java -cp . SleepMessages > c:\temp\output.txt 2>&1

C:\temp>type c:\temp\output.txt
Hi stderr!
Hi stdout!
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

How this can be explained? Is there any way to make this line the first one in the redirected output?

Java version and Windows version:

```
C:\temp>java -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
openjdk version "1.8.0_282"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_282-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.282-b08, mixed mode)

C:\temp>ver -a

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.867]
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm perfectly fine with this message being printed. What i wonder -- is why it is printed on the first line in one case and on the last line in another case

Comment: I cannot reproduce the reordering on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04, Java 8).  The "Picked up ..." message is always the first line.

Comment: Thanks! Must be something specific to the Windows, or how java is implemented on  Windows.

Comment: Also not reproducable on OpenJDK16 on Windows, maybe is 1.8 issue with how standard error streams are set up.

Comment: Indeed, with AdoptOpenJDK 11 I also don't see this behavior